# Is there any direct function to get indices of all possible matches in an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I generally find indexOf very useful, to get an index directly, and not writing 3-4 lines of for loop to get a match. 
Is there any similar function, say like indicesOf , to get an array of all possible matches ? 
Or may be having a different name, but acts as a shortcut as beautifully as "indexOf" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't mind creating a new Array, you can use the `filter()` function - it executes a function on each item of the array, then returns a new Array with the items that return `true`:

```
// our comparison function
function myCompFunction( element:*, index:int, array:Array ):Boolean
{
    return ( element > 10 );
}

var ar:Array = [5,10,15,20];
var ar2:Array = ar.filter( myCompFunction ); // ar2 is now [15,20]
```

It's not exactly indicies, but then again, you don't need to dereference your objects.

NOTE: because it's calling a function on each element, looping through the array yourself will still be quicker

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter()

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not such shortcut. `indexOf` works for only one item, and there is no alternative for multiple items.
The solutions are obvious - iterate over the entire array or use some kind of sort on the array. Maybe there are other methods, but they are almost the same - loop through everything and check. Sorry to say it, but that's the way it is :)